# How to make an ExtJS grid panel a true readonly component

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am using an 'Ext.grid.GridPanel' to disaply tabular data, and I am looking for a way to disable selection **and** focus on the HTML generated.

So far I have seen that using the `disableSelection` config, works for disable the selection, but is still possible to focus a row or cell in the grid.

To disable focus and selection, I have seen that the `disabled` config option do what I want, but I was thinking it is rather a side a side effect, as my understading of disabling something something applies ontly to form elements.
Is this a safe practise ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this CSS for your grid to avoid selections

```
.x-grid-item-selected .x-grid-td {
   background-color: transparent;
}
```